# How did std::allocators allow to support near/far pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, allocator

Several sources ([1],[2]) mention that the purpose of std::allocator was to allow for different pointer types (near/far/huge) on 16 bit platforms and parts of this original design still remain in the standard.

My questions are:

1. How specifically did allocators work with different pointer types those days? For example, if near pointer is meaningless without a value in DS register, how could near pointer allocator be useful?
2. Was there something in allocator requirements which was removed from standard, totally breaking support for segmented memory? If not, are the same facilities still used on modern 16 bit platforms, shall one exist which has a c++ compiler?

[1] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LIb3L4vKZ7U

[2] Josuttis, The C++ Standard Library: A Tutorial and Reference

Comment: They define two nested types, `pointer` and `reference`, that can be defined to support alternative memory management schemes.

Comment: Yes, but it does not answer question how would such an allocator be useful with near pointers.

Comment: If I was trying to answer the question I’d have written an answer, not a comment.

Comment: AFAIR it never really worked. More specifically, I don't know of any C++ compiler supporting a segmented architecture. Allocators became actually useful only post-C11 (IMHO), when they were turned into Something Completely Different (tm).